# Can't get the file extension in Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I can't get the file extension after Flow sends me an email. I searched through the web and saw that I can use metadata, but after I added metadata, there's a condition but the expression for the condition won't work at all.

```
@not(empty(body('Get_file_content')))
```

I saw they used to have the advanced function but it's not available anymore. I cant add it in the expression either, as it's invalid.

Is there another way I can get the file extension in my email attachment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you retrieving the file content and properties from a SPO library and sending that as an email attachment? If you are reading file meta data properties, you can get the file extension from **File name with extension** ````outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/{FilenameWithExtension}']````

Comment: Yes, im trying to do that as my email attachment is without any extension which is hard for me to choose the program to open the file.

Comment: I think mine is retrieve from onedrive instead of SPO. sorry for the confusion. Now im only got parsejson -> get file content from path -> send email. So if i want the extension from my onedrive, how can i do that?

Comment: Let me check on that (OneDrive). will post my response as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact requirements, but the following example shows how to get files from OneDrive and send those files with **file extensions** as an email attachment.

Please see the screenshots and explanation below.

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 1.1

[image]

Expressions used from the Dynamic Content

```
Id: items('Apply_to_each')?['Id']

Display name: items('Apply_to_each')?['DisplayName']

File content: outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']
```

### Detail 2

[image]

### The final output

[image]

### Conclusion:

Similar way, we can attach multiple files from SPO document library

Comment: Thanks Rahman. But i got errors in step detail 1.1. It said enter a valid json. I got a few questions here: 1. in detail 1.1, the 3 expression used is select from dynamic content or i type in expression? 2. In detail 1, under condition for no, i put nothing?

Comment: You got error in step 1.1 for [Get file content] or [Send and email] action? You don't have to type in the expressions, you could select those values from the Dynamic content. I've shown the expressions for reference purpose only. For condition, in this case, that is, **Is folder?**, you need to put "true"  in the expression panel  and then click "OK" as we're processing files only.